# Finding minimum value of $\frac12(\cos A\cos B+\cos B\cos C+\cos C\cos A)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Find minimum value of $\frac12(\cos A\cos B+\cos B\cos C+\cos C\cos A)$, when $A+B+C=\pi$

I found a solution on Quora. I am posting it here.

If all three cosines are negative then our expression would become positive. For minimum, only two cosines will be of same sign. The third will be opposite sign. Without loss of generality, let's take $\cos C$ to be of the opposite sign. Taking $\cos^2C$ common, our expression becomes $$\frac{\cos^2C}2\left(\frac{\cos A}{\cos C}\frac{\cos B}{\cos C}+\frac{\cos B}{\cos C}+\frac{\cos A}{\cos C}\right)\\=\frac{\cos^2C}2\left(\left(\frac{-\cos A}{\cos C}\right)\left(\frac{-\cos B}{\cos C}\right)-\left(\frac{-\cos B}{\cos C}\right)-\left(\frac{-\cos A}{\cos C}\right)\right)\\=\frac{\cos^2C}2(ab-b-a)$$

where $a=-\frac{\cos A}{\cos C}$, $b=-\frac{\cos B}{\cos C}$. The expression can be written as $$\frac{\cos^2C}2(-1+(1-a)(1-b))$$

For minimum, $a=1=b$

**My doubt**: can't $1-a$ be negative and at the same time $1-b$ be positive? i.e. $a>1,b<1$ i.e. $$-\frac{\cos A}{\cos C}>1,0<-\frac{\cos B}{\cos C}<1$$

Say, $-\frac{\cos A}{\cos C}=\frac{0.8}{0.3},-\frac{\cos B}{\cos C}=\frac{0.2}{0.3}$. Is something like this possible?

**Method 2:**$$\frac14(2\cos A\cos B+2\cos B\cos C+2\cos C\cos A)\\=\frac14((\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)^2-(\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C))$$

Now, I know $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C\ge-3$, when $A+B+C=\pi$ $(A=-\pi,B=-\pi,C=3\pi)$. Using this, the above expression is greater than or equal to $$\frac14(9-(\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C))$$

$\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C=1-2\cos A\cos B\cos C$, when $A+B+C=\pi$. Using this, the above expression is greater than or equal to $$\frac14(8+2\cos A\cos B\cos C)$$

$\cos A\cos B\cos C\ge-1$. Thus, the required minimum value is $\frac32$, which is incorrect.

**What's wrong in Method $2$**?

Comment: [This AOPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h542227p3126169) shows the maximum to be $\frac 38$ so a minimum of $\frac 32$ is absurd.

Comment: The issue with method 2 is that you say that if $x>-3$ then $x^2>(-3)^2=9$. Take any $x$ in the $(-3,3)$ range and you see that's not true. You can square both sides of an inequality and keep the inequality symbol **only** if both sides are positive.

Comment: @Andrei thanks a lot.